# Unable to put Values to a TreeMap Java

Tags: java

I have

```
Treemap<String, Student>
```

class where Student is

```
TreeMap<Integer, Person>
```

students where `Person` is object.
When I do

```
class.put(String, students)
```

I am getting error:

```
no suitable method found for put(String, TreeMap<Integer, Object>) java
```

Comment: What is "class" in your code? Please post complete snippet not just two lines of code.

Comment: Please edit your question and include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Do not post code in comments, add it to your question so that you can format it and make it readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Treemap<String, Studdent>` is a collection, in this case a map, where objects of the Student class are to be stored using String values as keys. The error you made is using the string class name as the key. So you should do something like:

```
Person = new Person(name, ssn, birthday);
int studentId = 1297;
TreeMap<Integer,Person> student = new TreeMap<>();
student.put(studentId, Person);
String className = "classOf2018";
TreeMap<String, TreeMap<Integer,Person>> class2018 = new TreeMap<>();   
class2018.put(className, student);
```

Comment: Person = new Person(name, ssn, birthday);
int studentId = 1297;
TreeMap<Integer,Person> Student = new TreeMap<>();
Student.put(studentId, Person);
String className = "classOf2018";
TreeMap<String, Student> class = new TreeMap<>();
myMap.put(className, s); => no suitable method for put(String, TreeMap<Integer, Object>)

Comment: @busy.me try again. I just used your code in my answer. Avoid using key words ( like class) for variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Your object `class` is of type `TreeMap<String, Student>` and not `TreeMap<String, TreeMap<Integer, Person>`

What you are doing when you do `class.put(String, students)` is that your're adding a key of type `String` mapped to value of type `TreeMap<Integer, Person>` due to which it throws an error whereas your map object expects a value of type `Student`.

Either change the type of `class` to `TreeMap<String, TreeMap<Integer, Person>` or add a `Student` object as a value to `class`.

Hope this helps.